# need help about process

Tags: java

when i start process like `process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnome-terminal");`, it start shell execution, i want to stop shell execution and want to redirect I/O from process, can anybody tell how i can do this?

my code is:

```
public void start_process()
{
     try
     {
         process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash");
         pw= new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream(),true);
         br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
         err=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

     }
     catch (Exception ioe)
     {
         System.out.println("IO Exception-> " + ioe);
     }


}

public void execution_command()
{

    if(check==2)
    {
        try
        {
            boolean flag=thread.isAlive();
            if(flag==true)
                thread.stop();

            Thread.sleep(30);
            thread = new MyReader(br,tbOutput,err,check);
            thread.start();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage()+"1");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(30);
            thread = new MyReader(br,tbOutput,err,check);
            thread.start();
            check=2;

        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage()+"1");
        }

    }
}

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    command=tfCmd.getText().toString().trim();

    pw.println(command);

    execution_command();

}
```

when i enter some command in textfield and press execute button, nothing displayed on my output textarea, how i can stop shellexecution and can redirect Input and output?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html):

> The `ProcessBuilder.start()` and `Runtime.exec()` methods create a native process and return an instance of a subclass of `Process` that can be used to control the process and obtain information about it. The class `Process` provides methods for performing input from the process, performing output to the process, waiting for the process to complete, checking the exit status of the process, and destroying (killing) the process.
>
> The methods that create processes may not work well for special processes on certain native platforms, such as native windowing processes, daemon processes, Win16/DOS processes on Microsoft Windows, or shell scripts. The created subprocess does not have its own terminal or console. All its standard io (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be redirected to the parent process through three streams (`getOutputStream()`, `getInputStream()`, `getErrorStream()`). The parent process uses these streams to feed input to and get output from the subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

In other words, after connecting a buffered stream reader to [`process.getInputStream()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) as you did, you should read all its output in order to make it run properly.

**Update:** [here is a simple example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ReadFromCommand.html) how to do it.